# How to set handlebars template value to a div as Id

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to set a random value which I got like this

```
{{id}}
```

I would like to set above id to a div Id.

example:
I have set like below.

```
<div id={{id}} class="lftblk"></div>
```

Expected result:

```
<div id="value_0" class="lftblk"></div>
```

But, I am getting metamorph in div. Hence, I wasn't able to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the use the bind-attr helper.

example

```
<div class="ui left labeled icon input" {{bind-attr id=yourattribute}}>
```

If you however don't want to bind it, you can use the unbound helper.

```
<div class="ui left labeled icon input" id="{{unbound yourattribute}}">
```